# Date not available php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When a use make a get form my website for a date that is not yet available in the database he get something like 1, Jan 1970.

```
<?php echo date("D j, M Y", strtotime($row["DATE"])); ?>
```

how to give " not yet available instead of the 1,jan 1970

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `IF`

```
if ($row["DATE"] != '' || $row["DATE"] != '0000-00-00')
{
    echo date("D j, M Y", strtotime($row["DATE"]));
}
else
{
    echo 'not yet available';
}
```

Comment: does not work example http://www.website.com/check.php?2012-02-29 still give 1,Jan11970

Comment: add another check to see if entered date is greater that current date

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by mysql depends on column datatype if you have datetime or timestamp the value returned would be 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and if you have date then value would be 0000-00-00. Try using this

```
if ($row["DATE"] != '' || $row["DATE"] != '0000-00-00' || $row["DATE"] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
{
    echo date("D j, M Y", strtotime($row["DATE"]));
}
else
{
    echo 'not yet available';
}
```

You can shorten the if statement if you know how the value stored in database when date is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` returns FALSE or -1 (depends on which version of PHP you're running). Just check for this case.

```
$date = strtotime($ROW['DATE']);
// need to change this next line depending on PHP version!
if ($date === false || $date == -1) {
  print "Not yet available";
} else {
  print date("D j, M Y", $date);
}
```